# Removing windows from a STL truck

Tags: extrude, 3d-printing

I have a STL which I need to remove the windows from.
I have dissolved the faces to form one workable face.
My problem is I need to push this through to the other side but keep the object solid.
I can extrude the face but obviously it does not match up on the other side.
I need to keep the object watertight as I will be 3d printing it.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: delete window, select edge loops on both sides and use bridge tool ... BTW now I checked your blend - seems to be done as solid ... now I don't understand your Q.

Comment: The object is a solid, but I need to remove the windows and leave space in the cab for 3d printed figures. I will then reglaze the windows with glass. If I just remove the glass and export the object as a STL it will auto repair in my slicer and fill the window gaps in again.

Comment: I have used the edge loop and bridge method on the side windows and it works perfectly, the front windows are another problem.

Comment: Sorry but your screens shows what you described, but provided blend file has already glass deleted and holes filled https://imgur.com/jlIQ1xB ... so the only one difference that you mentioned in comment now is you need space for figures?

Comment: There must be confusion on what I am trying to achieve. I used the loop bridge to delete side windows. I have used Boolean to cut the front windows out. As pictures above.

Comment: Big mistake I uploaded the wrong file to start with, new file added.